# Receiving denormalized output texture coordinates in Frag shader

Tags: webgl2

**Update**

See rationale at the end of my question below

---

Using `WebGL2` I can access a texel by its denormalized coordinates (sorry don't the right lingo for this). That means I don't have to scale them down to 0-1 like I do in `texture2D()`.
However the input to the fragment shader is still the `vec2/3` in normalized values.

Is there a way to declare in/out variables in the Vertex and Frag shaders so that I don't have to scale the coordinates?

somewhere in vertex shader:

```
...
out vec2 TextureCoordinates;
```

somewhere in frag shader:

```
...
in vec2 TextureCoordinates;
```

I would like for `TextureCoordinates` to be `ivec2` and already scaled.

This question and all my other questions on webgl related to general computing using WebGL. We are trying to do tensor (multi-D matrix) operations using WebGL.

We map our data in a few ways to a Texture. The simplest approach we follow is -- assuming we can access our data as a flat array -- to lay it out along the texture's width and go up the texture's height until we're done.

Since our thinking, logic, and calculations are all based on tensor/matrix indices -- inside the fragment shader -- we'd have to map back to/from the X-Y texture coordinates to indices. The intermediate step here is to calculate an offset for a given position of a texel. Then from that offset we can calculate the matrix indices from its strides.

Calculating an offset in webgl 1 for very large textures seems to be taking much longer than webgl2 using the integer coordinates. See below:

**WebGL 1 offset calculation**

```
  int coordsToOffset(vec2 coords, int width, int height) {
    float s = coords.s * float(width);
    float t = coords.t * float(height);
    int offset = int(t) * width + int(s);
    return offset;
  }
  vec2 offsetToCoords(int offset, int width, int height) {
    int t = offset / width;
    int s = offset - t*width;
    vec2 coords = (vec2(s,t) + vec2(0.5,0.5)) / vec2(width, height);
    return coords;
  }
```

**WebGL 2 offset calculation in the presence of int coords**

```
int coordsToOffset(ivec2 coords, int width) {
    return coords.t * width + coords.s;
}
ivec2 offsetToCoords(int offset, int width) {
  int t = offset / width;
  int s = offset - t*width;
  return ivec2(s,t);
}
```

It should be clear that for a series of large texture operations we're saving hundreds of thousands of operations just on the offset/coords calculation.

Comment: What do you expect to achieve? Why do you need them in texels instead of normalized coordinates? First off integer values are not interpolated; Second you can just use a vec2 varying and then `ivec2(someVec2)` but of course you'll only get the exact pixel, no sampling. 3rd, given the texture dimensions are passed in to the shader it's trival to use normalized coordinates in WebGL2 where appropriate

Comment: What I am hoping to do is save computation time by not doing the following: `ivec2 denormCoords = ivec2(TextureCoordinates.x * theTextureWidth, TextureCoordinates.y * theTextureHeight)`

Comment: what are you actually trying to do ? not what code you're trying to do it with. why are you passing in normalized coords and multiplying by dimensions? if you want denormalized coords why not just pass in denormalized coords? separately , gpus are pipelined. it's possible you'll save time but it's also possible you won't save anytime. it's also possible you'll lose time.

Comment: I think what I'm questioning is how can I pass denormalized coordiantes to my fragment shader? Is it a matter of declaring `out ivec2 TextureCoordinates;` in my vertex shader? (changing vec2 to ivec2?)

Comment: As It said above, integer varyings will not be interpolated so if that's ok then yes you can do that. Or just pass un-normalized vec2 and convert to ivec2 in fragment shader as I wrote above. You still haven't said what you're trying to actually do. Draw a triangle? Sum some values? Compute a post processing glow? What?

Comment: see updates to the original post please for motivation. thanks a lot for taking the time to look in my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you want do what you're trying to do. It would be better to ask something like "I'm trying to draw an image/implement post processing glow/do ray tracing/... and to do that I want to use un-normalized texture coordinates because " and then we can tell you if your solution is going to work and how to solve it.

In any case, passing `int` or `unsigned int` or `ivec2/3/4` or `uvec2/3/4` as a varying is supported but **not interpolation**. You have to declare them as `flat`.

Still, you can pass un-normalized values as `float` or `vec2/3/4` and the convert to `int`, `ivec2/3/4` in the fragment shader.

The other issue is you'll get no sampling using `texelFetch`, the function that takes texel coordinates instead of normalized texture coordinates. It just returns the exact value of a single pixel. It does not support filtering like the normal `texture` function.

Example:

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert("need webgl2");
  }
  
  const vs = `
   #version 300 es
   in vec4 position;
   in ivec2 texelcoord;
   
   out vec2 v_texcoord;
   
   void main() {
      v_texcoord = vec2(texelcoord);
      gl_Position = position;
   }
  `;
  
  const fs = `
  #version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  in vec2 v_texcoord;
  out vec4 outColor;
  uniform sampler2D tex;
  
  void main() {
    outColor = texelFetch(tex, ivec2(v_texcoord), 0);
  }
  `;
  
  // compile shaders, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  // create buffers via gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData)
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
      -.5, -.5,
       .5, -.5,
        0,  .5,
      ],
    },
    texelcoord: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: new Int32Array([
        0,  0,
       15,  0,
        8, 15,
      ]),
    }
  });
  
  // make a 16x16 texture
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = 16;
  ctx.canvas.height = 16;
  for (let i = 23; i > 0; --i) {
    ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${i / 23 * 360 | 0}, 100%, ${i % 2 ? 25 : 75}%)`;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(8, 15, i, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();
  }
  const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, { src: ctx.canvas });
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  // no need to set uniforms since they default to 0
  // and only one texture which is already on texture unit 0
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
main();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

So in response to your updated question it's still not clear what you want to do. Why do you want to pass varyings to the fragment shader? Can't you just do whatever math you want in the fragment shader itself?

Example:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
out float result;

// some all the values in the texture
vec4 sum4 = vec4(0);
ivec2 texDim = textureSize(tex, 0);
for (int y = 0; y < texDim.y; ++y) {
  for (int x = 0; x < texDim.x; ++x) {
    sum4 += texelFetch(tex, ivec2(x, y), 0);
  }
}
result = sum4.x + sum4.y + sum4.z + sum4.w;
```

Example2

```
uniform isampler2D indices;
uniform sampler2D data;

out float result;

// some only values in data pointed to by indices
vec4 sum4 = vec4(0);
ivec2 texDim = textureSize(indices, 0);
for (int y = 0; y < texDim.y; ++y) {
  for (int x = 0; x < texDim.x; ++x) {
    ivec2 index = texelFetch(indices, ivec2(x, y), 0).xy;
    sum4 += texelFetch(tex, index, 0);
  }
}
result = sum4.x + sum4.y + sum4.z + sum4.w;
```

Note that I'm also not an expert in GPGPU but I have an hunch the code above is not the fastest way because I believe parallelization happens based on output. The code above has only 1 output so no parallelization? It would be easy to change so that it takes a block ID, tile ID, area ID as input and computes just the sum for that area. Then you'd write out a larger texture with the sum of each block and finally sum the block sums.

Also, dependant and non-uniform texture reads are a known perf issue. The first example reads the texture in order. That's cache friendly. The second example reads the texture in a random order (specified by indices), that's not cache friendly.

Comment: thanks a lot man. Sorry about that. I didn't understand what the question was. I'm going to edit my main post and add a lot more details

Comment: I tried changing `vec2` to `ivec2` and problems start to happen. First I had to add `flat` as a qualifier in the frag shader. Then I had to add `flat` to `out` variable in the vertex shader. Then I got the error `vertexAttrib function must match shader attrib type`. Looking back at the code you posted, it looks like the texture coodinates in the vertex buffer need to be also be specified in the non-interpolated way. I think this is going to diminish any gains we'll get by having to change the vertex buffer for each output texture. So far we only created this buffer once and it was  0.0 to 1.0

Comment: Not sure you what you mean. I passed in Int32s for texcoords. I converted them to floats in the shader. passed them to the fragment shader as floats, converted back to ints. They are never 0 to 1. They are always int values. Floats stay ints for values from 0 to 2^23 or something like that. As for your error `vertexAttrib function must match shader attrib type` that sounds like you called `vertexAttrib4f` instead of `vertexAttrib4i` or `vertexAttrib4ui`?

Comment: Correct. What i was saying was so far we got away by creating one geometry at the beginning of our app. That geometry specified the texture dimensions to be a square at (0,0) of length 1. But now it looks like we have to specify the real dimensions of the texture we are bounding to the output in the geometry. Which means a geometry change every time we change the output texture and call draw(). I hope my understanding is correct. And if so -- and I haven't tried this -- we may not gain any performance time if not lose some due to the geometry updates?

Comment: Why do you have to update the geometry?  `gl_Position = vec2_scale_uniform * unitSquarePosition`?

Comment: I can't pass 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 , 1, 1, 0 in my vertex buffer. Can I? I am looking at your example and you have real dimensions such as 8 x 15 in your texel coordinates. I am guessing those are the output texture dimensions you're writing to. So if I swap output textures, I am guessing I would need to update those coordinates by making a call to `gl.bufferData()` and/or `gl.vertexAttribPointer()`, `gl.enableVertexAttribArray()`?

Comment: In the examples above I'm using input texture size. You can use any size you want. I just used `textureSize` to show you there's a GLSL function in WebGL2 that returns the size of a texture. In my example the output texture size is 1x1 pixels but as I pointed out you can easily change that. I'm pretty confused at your confusion. It's common to pass in a unit square and multiply that by something in your vertex shader. [Here's a page of examples where new vertices are never updated](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-drawimage.html). Just a single unit square.